# Реализация наклона к земле/тангажа для физического снаряда

Tags: unity3d

3D проект, имеется снаряд с Rigidbody. Необходимо заставить его наклоняться "головой" к земле аки стрелу. Догадываюсь, что нужно к чему-то цеплять rotation, но не представляю, к чему.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: К вектору движения как не странно. `transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(body.velocity)`

Answer (score -1):

В общем, задача оказалась куда проще, чем казалось на первый взгляд.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MissieRotator : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody ref_rigidbody;
    private void Start()
    {

        ref_rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        transform.eulerAngles -= (new Vector3(ref_rigidbody.velocity.x ,0)); 
        
    }

}
```